# appending only date from movies list

Tags: python, append

i have an imdb top250 list of movies with release year at the end. i only want to append the release years from the whole list. this is my try so far:

```
from pprint import pprint
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

top250 = []
newPath = []
ratings = []

top250 = open("top250ratings.list", "r")
lines = top250.readlines()
newPath = (lines[14:])
for row in newPath:
    names.append(row[32:])        

pprint (names)
```

part of output:

```
[' The Shawshank Redemption (1994)\n',
'The Godfather (1972)\n',
'The Godfather: Part II (1974)\n',
' The Dark Knight (2008)\n',
```

Comment: So what have you *actually tried* to achieve that? Do you have *any* ideas as to how you could extract the years? You could look into e.g. [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: we have tried to .split(" ") but it didnt work because list has no attribute split

Comment: You need to split `str`ings (e.g. `row`) not `list`s (e.g. `names`).

Comment: so i have to open my file in another way?

Comment: That's not at all what I said. You need to process each item in the list with `split`, not the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[' The Shawshank Redemption (1994)\n',
'The Godfather (1972)\n',
'The Godfather: Part II (1974)\n',
' The Dark Knight (2008)\n',]

for i in l:
    print i[:-1].split()[-1] # remove "\n", split and get last element

(1994)
(1972)
(1974)
(2008)
```

If you want to remove the parens:

```
print i[:-1].split()[-1][1:-1]
1994
1972
1974
2008
```

You can adapt that to get the content you need.